# Persistent Error in R match.fun(FUN) : 'scales$transform_df' is not a function, character or symbol

Tags: ggplot2, scaletransform

I execute the following script (... in place of actuals for space):

```
animated_ggplot <- ggplot(...,
                      aes(...,...,size=...,colour=...)) + 
geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
scale_x_log10() +
labs(x="X-axis title)", 
   y="y-axis title)") +
transition_time(year)
animated_ggplot
anim_save("animated_ggplot.gif")
```

I have installed and loaded the following packages:

gifski, tweenr, devtools, thomasp85/transformr, tomasp85/gganimate, gganimate, png.

Everything seems to work well until "animated_ggplot", which results in the error.

Using ggplot2 ver.3.4.3

Any suggestions or points of reference to possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with the following procedure:

First, reinstalled R (4.3.1-x86_64.pkg) and R Studio (3.3.0). The platform I am using is an intel based macbook pro mid-2015.

I believe the main problem was being caused by being instructed to install the following:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github('thomasp85/transformr')
devtools::install_github('thomasp85/gganimate')
```

This time, I did not install "devtools" since it's already in the packages for the latest R version (as of this post).

In addition, I installed "transformr" and "gganimate" from:

```
install.packages('transformr')
install.packages('gganimate')
```

This resolved my issue.